# Add scheduled page or post in the menu section on back-end

Tags: menus, scheduled-posts

I want to add scheduled page/post in the menu section on back-end before publish the page/post. Please see the screenshot:

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the future pages with the filter `nav_menu_items_page`

**Notes:**

1. You can do the same with the posts or other cpt by changing the post
   type in the hook `nav_menu_items_{$post_type}`
2. This filter is for the **View All** tab in the pages.

**Example:**

```
function add_scheduled_pages($posts, $args, $post_type) {
    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_status' => array('publish', 'future')
        )
    );

    $posts = $query->posts;
    return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_items_page', 'add_scheduled_pages', 10, 3 );
```

Now you can add futures pages to the menu but this pages will show in the front end menu too.

So now you need to filter all the future pages and remove them from the front end.

Its can be done with the filter `wp_nav_menu_objects`

```
function remove_future_pages($sorted_menu_items, $args) {
    $filter_futures = array_filter($sorted_menu_items, function($item) {
        if(get_post_status($item->object_id) !== 'future') {
            return $item;
        }
    });
    return $filter_futures;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'remove_future_pages', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks